# Android: retrieving current resource in the ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I created an ImageView and in my activity every few seconds i change the picture to a different one. I also have a button than when press, is supposed to get me the resource id of the picture currently being displayed, the problem is that everytime i do:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

It always gives me the resourceId defined in the xml, not the one i changed dynamically, how can i achieve this? here's the code in my activity class:

```
public void startImages(View v) {
   ...
       delayedImage(0); 
}

private void delayedImage(final int index) {
    //stop at the 5th picture
    if (index > 5) return;

    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String drawableId = "picture" +index;
            int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableId, "drawable", getPackageName());
            ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            view.setImageResource(resourceId);
            delayedImage(index+1);
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

So every 5 second a new image is set, when i click on the button Share I want to retrieve whatever resourceId is currently in the ImageView set in the method above.

```
//send image to send text
public void shareImage(View v){
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ??????
}
```

I checked the ImageView object while debugging and I saw someone get the int by doing this:

```
Field f = ImageView.class.getDeclaredField("mResource");
f.setAccessible(true);
Object out = f.get(view);
```

But i'm unable to get the actual R drawable name from this which I need when i'm trying to retrieve it from

```
String path = "android.resource://your.package.name/" +getPackageName() +"/" +???;
```

.. can anyone please help?